# how can i put the right value for each cell in excel?

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, analysis

I have a question about my excel file, maybe someone can help me in excel or R I'll solve this,

I have three columns, year and engine size, and the third column; are engine sizes for 2015, I need to map them to suitable cells, for example, 998 should be in cell B10,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwAmf.png)

Comment: Data validation may work.

Comment: Why does `998` go in `b10`? What about `1197`? Does that go somewhere? If so, why?

Comment: the third column is the engine size for 2015 vehicles based on make/models, so the first one 998 should be in B10 since the year is 2015, then the second one 1197 should be in B21, until all of the 2015 cells have a value in the second column,

Comment: Try pasting the following into cell B2 and dragging the fill handle down to cell B25: =IF(A2<>2015,"",INDEX(C$2:C$25,COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,2015)))